# How do I prove the subset of this ring is an ideal

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, ring-theory

I'm trying to prove that this subset of an unital commutative ring $R$ is an ideal:

$I$ is an ideal of $R[X]$. For all $i\in \mathbb N$, we have

$$L_i(I):=\left\{a_i\in R:\text{ there exist }a_{i-1}, \ldots,a_0\in R\text{ with }\sum_{j=0}^i a_jX^j\in I\right\}$$

I've already proved that if $a,b\in L_i(I)$ and $r\in R$, then $a+b\in L_i(I)$ and $ra\in L_i(I)$, but I couldn't prove the easier part, how do I prove that $L_i$ is non-empty?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: $0 \in L_i(I)$, because the zero polynomial is in $I$.

Comment: it's true, thank you very much.

Comment: @DanielFischer Please put comments in comments and answers in answers, and not crosswise :) [We](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/9141/the-crusade-of-answers) want to get this out of the unanswered question queue asap!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Typically, the easiest way to show that a set is non-empty when one wants to prove that it is an ideal/a linear subspace/a subgroup... is to show that it contains $0$ (the identity element).

It is here too.

Since you start with an ideal $I \subset R[X]$, you know that $0 \in I$ ($0$ here is the zero polynomial), and therefore $\sum\limits_{j = 0}^i 0\cdot X^j \in I$ (here, the $0$ is the zero of $R$ for the coefficients), hence $0 \in L_i(I)$. If $I = (p)$ is a principal ideal, and $R$ an integral domain, then that is the only element of $L_i(I)$ for $i < \deg p$.